# postgreSQL query over several very large tables with same columns , how to optimize it and its code

Tags: postgresql

I am runining a following "simple query" from tables a1, a2, ..., a20. each table a1, a2, ...., a20 has milions of rows, and each of them have same columns, X, Y, Z.

```
CREATE TABLE A_bis as
SELECT
  X,  Y,  Z
FROM a1
WHERE
Y= 3
UNION
SELECT
  X,  Y,  Z
FROM a2
WHERE
Y= 3
UNION
SELECT
  X,  Y,  Z
FROM a3
WHERE
Y= 3
UNION
...
SELECT
  X,  Y,  Z
FROM a20
WHERE
Y= 3
```

and I get table A_bis, but it takes at least 20 minutes.
I'd like to:

a) optimize the query so it is faster.

b) improve the code (loop ? ) so I don't have to literally write a 7 lines for each of tables a1, .... a20 to get 130 lines of code

Comment: If Y is indexed, it shouldn't take 20 minutes. I think your column Y is not indexed and Postgres has to scan the whole table to find the value. As for your code, I don't think you can change a table name dynamically, but you can create queries in a SpreadSheet easily if that helps...

Comment: How to make the Y column indexed ?

Comment: You should seriously get a database training because this is beginner question which you shouldn't have to ask. Google is your friend.

Comment: I'm not sure that the problem is retrieving the information. How large will be the new table to be created? (How many rows satisfy the constraint Y=3 in your 20 tables?) Also, what are the types of X, Y and Z?

Comment: So who ever created the tables a1...a20 did it for the memory purpose, each of them is 1 GB....  there is probably 1 row taken every 4000 rows from each of a1...a20 table, each of a1...a20 table has like 300000 rows....

Comment: check this blog to see how indexes work and how they are used: http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Answer (score 1):

Comments answered your question A (Basically : Add an index on each aX table).

For the question B, you can use [PostgreSQL inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html):

```
CREATE TABLE aParent (x INT, y INT, z INT);
ALTER TABLE a1 INHERITS aParent;
ALTER TABLE a2 INHERITS aParent;
...
ALTER TABLE a20 INHERITS aParent;
```

Then you can do

```
SELECT X, Y, Z FROM aParent WHERE Y = 3;
```

Comment: thank you very much...So who ever created the tables a1...a20 did it for the memory purpose, each of them is 1 GB.... will your inheritance solution work on that ? on a laptop with 3 gb of free ram ?

Comment: It will work even with 64Mi of RAM. If you are concerned with performance you might be interested by the following page: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-CONSTRAINT-EXCLUSION which explains how to use inheritance at its best :-)